# post in facebook wall publicaly using graph

Tags: php, fb-graph

.   i want to post inside my fb wall as public post
before i post my question here i check all provided and similar questions that Stackoverflow provide 
they are all old & fb is update their api graph every year or even every months
please help:
i'm using some code ...

it's work for me but unfortunately it's post as a private & not as public.

Answer (score 0):

You can't post to a personal profile at all [since 2018](https://www.businessinsider.com/facebook-no-longer-lets-apps-automatically-post-to-your-profile-2018-4), and there's no privacy setting for Page/Group posts... so this isn't going to work. If others aren't seeing your posts, it's because your app is in development mode instead of being live.

Comment: but i have already the ability to post to any page or group and in a public mode
and i have seen also an android app that can do what i'm asking here in public mode too using graph api

Comment: Page posts are always public. Group posts inherit the permissions of the Group. I can't speak to a particular Android app, but the official Facebook API simply doesn't permit posts to personal profiles anymore.

Comment: so sir.     what exactly i need to do plz in order to make my post work inside a personal profile as public mode
i know a web application can do that without any problems
can you clarify for me plz

Comment: **You cannot post to a personal profile using the Facebook API.**

Comment: @Pedro My suspicion is you're using an API token from the official Facebook app instead of one obtained legitimately through Facebook's OAuth flow. Doing so would be a violation of the Facebook terms.